# EasyPHP - Need to recrearte MySQL user everytime

Tags: mysql, easyphp

Whenever I restart EasyPHP I need to deleted and then create my database user before my local site starts working again.

I am not sure if this helps but I often see the following

2017-10-07T09:34:24.030014Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '*D088F901C439D7A141E3CD97FDB670AEAACF0C42' used to authenticate user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.

Comment: That looks to me like your `authentication_string` is being interpreted as a plugin.  I'm not familiar with EasyPHP, but it sounds like your MySQL needs to be upgraded (i.e. `mysql_upgrade`).

Comment: Thanks, I have Googled to try and find out what I need to do. When I try run mysql_upgrade (or variations of it) I get the following error mysql> mysql_upgrade;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql
_upgrade' at line 1

Comment: If you don't MySQL command prompt access, you won't be able to upgrade with that command.  I don't have any familiarity with easyphp to be able to offer any specific advice, other than "reinstall the latest version" I'm afraid.

Comment: I do have MySQL access as I can list databases and tables from the MYSQL prompt but MySQL_UPGRADE returns the above error so was just wondering if I was getting something wrong in the syntax.

Comment: Andre - might be best to consult the documentation to confirm the method you're using https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html